# my app installed weird between iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an Enterprise Account(installing via Over The Air). I made a test app, which is a universal app, and i tested it on my device. But it installed in a strange manner.

If i install the app, you can see the installation icon on the iPhone app doubled(see two app icons). but on iPad it doesn't happen. I don't know why?

First, I thought that it's because of the hardware difference of the two devices. But the app size is only just 2.7MB, so I expect that both devices can easily handle the app.

The following link shows this issue: [this link shows weird app installing situation](http://bizmob.mcnc.co.kr:90/iPhone/mov/iOSinstall.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are installing over the air(via a download link with configured plist), probably the "bundle identifier" set on the plist of your download link, doesn't match the "bundle identifier" of the app being downloaded. This is usually caused by reusing your plist(with old/wrong bundle identifier) for download instead of making a new one.

Comment: I experienced this problem also a few months ago, that's why when I read your question, I quickly understood what's happening to you.

Answer (score 0):

Run a clean in Xcode and then delete the app from the device itself and then try again